# DOMDocument - Directly load XML file from php://input

Tags: php

Currently I have a PHP file that reads posted XML and then converts/outputs it to JSON. This file looks like this:

```
<?php 

file_put_contents('myxmlfile.xml', file_get_contents('php://input'));
$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load("myxmlfile.xml");
$xpathvar = new DOMXPath($xmldoc);

// Etc etc, for the purpose of my question seeing the rest isn't necessary
// After finishing the conversion I save the file as a JSON file.

file_put_contents('myjsonfile.json', $JSONContent);

?>
```

The data I'm receiving comes in XML format. To convert it I'm currently saving it as an XML file, and then immediately after creating a new `DOMDocument()` and loading it in. My question is, is there any way I can cut out the middle man and just load in the XML directly using `file_get_contents()`?

Ideally it would be this (didn't work):

```
$xmldoc->load(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

If anyone could help me do this I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load from string, instead of filename, use [loadXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) method.

```
$xmldoc->loadXML(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```